# Trying to display image in a game of memory

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Okay, so this is my problem. I'm creating a game of memory with some images in it. I cannot understand how I would be able to display the image after setting it to display='none' with the for-loop onLoad function.

I've tried for a couple of hours now without result. =(

Anyone that can help me?

And also elem.id points to a td id so it's dynamic. It's tricky because in every td there is an img.

I sincerely appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
    var clicked = true;
    var firstClick;
    var secondClick;
    var firstPlayer = true;
    var addPointPlayer1 = 0;
    var addPointPlayer2 = 0;
    var totalPoints = 8;


    function clickCard(elem){       

    //document.getElementsByTagName('img').style.display = "";

    if(clicked){
        firstClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);
    //  document.getElementsByName(/.img/).style.visibility="visible";
        firstClick.style.backgroundColor= "white";
        clicked = false;

        }

    else{

        secondClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        secondClick.style.backgroundColor = "white";


            if(firstClick.innerHTML == secondClick.innerHTML){
                firstClick.style.backgroundColor="white";
                secondClick.style.backgroundColor="white";
                if(firstPlayer){
                    addPointPlayer1++;
                    totalPoints--;
                    }
                else{
                    addPointPlayer2++;
                    totalPoints--;
                    }

                }


            else {
                alert('This is not a pair, player change');
                firstClick.style.backgroundColor="#7f1a1a"; 
                secondClick.style.backgroundColor="#7f1a1a";
                if(firstPlayer){
                    firstPlayer = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        firstPlayer = true;
                    }           
                }

            clicked = true;

            }

            //Keeping control of the winner
            if(totalPoints == 0){
                if(addPointPlayer1 > addPointPlayer2){
                    alert("Game over! Player 1 wins with " +    addPointPlayer1 + " points" + addPointPlayer2);
                    }
                    else if (addPointPlayer1 == addPointPlayer2){
                        alert("This is a draw press cmd+R for a rematch");
                        }

                else{
                    alert("Game over! Player 2 wins with " + addPointPlayer2 + " points against " + addPointPlayer1);
                    }
            }

    }

    //creates a blank game-plan
    function hideGamePlan(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (i = 0; i < images.length;i++ ) {
        images[i].style.display = "none";

    }

}
```

Comment: If possible I'd suggest looking into `jQuery`. But onto your issue, if you give your images another attribute that you can identify them by, a simple index (0, 1, 2)(If you can use html5 I suggest 'data-somethinghere' attributes if not for standards sake stick to something like storing it in the `name` attribute) should suffice you can then set their `display` css property back to `inline` when you wan't to show them.

Comment: should I rename my images to 0,1,2?

Comment: look at jquery, you can do things like add css upon a click event, so add display block to override the display none

Comment: I wouldn't name your images in that way. Names and ids should generally begin with an underscore or a letter. Try something like im1, im2 for test purposes although you may wish to consider a more fitting name later on in development. http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name

Comment: @jezzipin +1 neat I didn't know there was open bnf docs on attributes. Also to further the idea above if you only need to show the one that is clicked, there is no need to identify them at all as the Event object will contain a handle to the clicked img somewhere along its chain. However it maybe useful to give them some sort of identifier for other purposes.

Comment: @BobbyFalck I would advise putting a working version of your code as it is so far in a JSFiddle and that way we can have a play around and help you with a solution. http://http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks @jezzipin. You've posted something which is good to know and follow stuff. great job.

Comment: @dennmat thanks for the reply, and to all of you really. The problem is that's some php in there to so I can't put it on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this with

```
 function clickCard(elem){      



    if(!clicked){
        firstClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        firstClick.style.backgroundColor= "white";
        findImage[firstClick.id-1].style.visibility="visible";
        clicked = true;
        //alert(findImage);

        }

    else{
        secondClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        secondClick.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        findImage[secondClick.id-1].style.visibility="visible"; 
    //  firstClick.getAttribute('src');
    //  secondClick.getAttribute('src');

            if(firstClick.innerHTML == secondClick.innerHTML){

                firstClick.style.backgroundColor="white";
                secondClick.style.backgroundColor="white";

                if(firstPlayer){
                    addPointPlayer1++;
                    totalPoints--;
                    }
                else{
                    addPointPlayer2++;
                    totalPoints--;
                    }

                }


            else {

                alert('This is not a pair, player change');

                firstClick.style.backgroundColor="#7f1a1a";
                secondClick.style.backgroundColor="#7f1a1a";
                findImage[firstClick.id-1].style.visibility="hidden";
                findImage[secondClick.id-1].style.visibility="hidden";


                if(firstPlayer){
                    firstPlayer = false;                        
                    //findImage[elem.id-1].style.visibility="hidden";
                    }
                    else{
                        firstPlayer = true;
                    }           
                }


            clicked = false;
            }

            //Keeping control of the winner
            if(totalPoints == 0){
                if(addPointPlayer1 > addPointPlayer2){
                    alert("Game over! Player 1 wins with " + addPointPlayer1 + " points" + addPointPlayer2);
                    }
                    else if (addPointPlayer1 == addPointPlayer2){
                        alert("This is a draw press cmd+R for a rematch");
                        }

                else{
                    alert("Game over! Player 2 wins with " + addPointPlayer2 + " points against " + addPointPlayer1);
                    }
            }


 }

 function hideGamePlan(){
findImage = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < findImage.length;i++ ) {
    findImage[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the display to none, then somewhere else you should be setting the display to something - ie block.

I recommend this for help: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it's not working. document.getElementsByTagName('img').style.display="block"; just interrupts the script.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you trying this in, and do you get any js errors in the console?

Comment: Ah = and doing a getElementsByTagname -  you mean to change *every* element to style block? That doesn't sound right - surely only the element that was clicked (or it's child).

Comment: Hmm, yes i figured that it wouldnt work. So the problem is when im initiating firstClick I want to set the img display back. Im on my phone right now. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

After `if(clicked){firstClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);`
I guess your problem is to find the children image tag element

if that is the case You may use find("img")

I mean

```
if(clicked){
        firstClick = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        elemtochange = firstClick.find("img");
        // Changing image style here
        elemtochange.style.display ="block";
}
```

Or you may want to look into Jquery to do the same for you by just

```
if (clicked){
     $(elem).children("img").show(); // elem = Clicked element
}
```

Instead of `show` you may use `hide` to hide the element or `toggle` to toggle the display between show and hide on every click

Comment: What **device** are you running on? Did you check **if javascript is disabled for the web page?** Are you getting **any error** while executing this script?
Please specify.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the response's! I ended up just placing the submit buttons up top..

```
<form action = "/memory-game/index.php" method = "POST">
<input type="submit" name="dog" value="Dog" />
<input type="submit" name="cat" value="Cat" />
<input type="submit" name="fish" value="Fish" />
<input type="submit" name="zoo" value="Zoo" />
<input type="submit" name="xmas" value="Xmas" />
<input type="submit" name="pen" value="Pengins" />
</form>
```

Then for the other page did this:

```
if(isset($_POST['dog'])){$currentArr = $dogArr;}
elseif(isset($_POST['cat'])){$currentArr = $catArr;}
elseif(isset($_POST['fish'])){$currentArr = $fishArr;}
elseif(isset($_POST['xmas'])){$currentArr = $xmasArr;}
elseif(isset($_POST['pen'])){$currentArr = $penginArr;}
elseif(isset($_POST['zoo'])){$currentArr = $zooArr;}
```